# How to use the flow label in IPv6 for QoS (video) on cisco router C7200P-ADVIPSERVICESK9-M

Tags: router, ipv6

I am currently testing IPv6 in a test environment for QoS testing.

I am testing QoS via VLC stream from 1 machine to another.
So far I was able to setup the tagging on the switch and the shaping on the router.

I saw via wireshark in the IPv6 field the DSCP value changed to AF31, so that is a success.

Now I am wondering how you can set the flow label.
But can't really find something regarding this in the cisco documents.
At this point I am afraid this is still something plannend for the future.

Anyone found this one out yet?
Any help or hint in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the flow label is something that _routers_ are supposed to set? AFAIK, it's meant to be set by end hosts, and _read_ by QoS-applying devices to identify flows.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I just assumed you had to set it at the router, because the router is the one who checks the package. I thought the way it worked was:
1. Router receives a package
2. Router decapsulates the package
3. Router checks the package and makes a decision what to do with it
4. Router encapsulates the package again
5. Router adds a flow label
6. Router forwards the packages

Thank you for your input grawity, I will investigate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people that have the same question, I found my answer here:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2460#appendix-A